# is there any way to make the platform independent files just like Dlls?

Tags: windows, macos, platform-independent

i am looking for some files like DLLs that can be used on windows as well as Mac OS is there any way of doing this will c++ or any other language that must be higher level than c++

need help regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java seems like an obvious choice. Java's variant of DLL files are JAR files, which can be used on any system that has a Java Runtime Environment. This includes Windows, Mac OS, Linux and various other operating systems.

And, Java is percieved as being "higher level" than C++, although language wars might arise once in a while about topics such as this one.